# Android SDK Manager fails on Windows 8 64bit

Tags: android, windows-8, eclipse-plugin, 64-bit

During installing Android SDKs in Eclipse - everything was fine.
When tried to open Android SDK manager from menu - it fails.
Tried to start program directly from folder. It fails againg.

```
[2013-03-20 10:47:42 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] 'D:\Android' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
[2013-03-20 10:47:42 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] operable program or batch file.
```

I've read many syggestions about enviroment path set in Windows, but Eclipse itsefl works fine, so this is not my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We all used to use folder names with space inside. I my case:

```
"d:\Android stuff"
```

All other products work fine with such folder names. Eclipse+Android too in WindowsXP.
But in Windows8 64 bit - Google SDK refuses to work with such names. When renamed folder to"

```
"d:\Androidstuff"
```

everyting works fine.

Probably We live in 21 century, but Google developers live in 19th century.

**Update**
In fact android developers team fixed this in next release. :)

Comment: Definetly! ""Probably We live in 21 century, but Google developers live in 19th century.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have got the same issue today, these kind of errors are because Android SDK doesn't support spaces in the folders names. The JDK and the Android SDK must be installed in folders without spaces.

C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 
**YES**

C:\Program Files(x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45 
**NO**